# Multiple sites under one subdomain

Tags: iis

We currently use a dev site for one of our web apps, dev.domain.com.  I'd like to add other dev sites to this subdomain.  For example, our mobile dev site would be dev.domain.com/mobile and our api dev site would be dev.domain.com/api.

I currently have them all set up as separate sites with separate physical directories in IIS.  How do I tell IIS to send users that go to dev.domain.com/mobile to the mobile physical directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the "dev.domain.com" website, and "Add Virtual Directory". Call it 'mobile', set the physical path to be the mobile site's folder.

Comment: Perfect!  As a side note, I had to convert it to an application as well.